# Why is AngularJS named AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and would like to have some intuition behind why it was named AngularJS. This intuition tends to help me think about the purpose and design principles behind a framework.

Edit: I guess I'm also looking for someway to connect the name to what it represents in it's design principles.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about why they named it what they did is not within the scope of problems Stack Overflow solves.

Comment: Why not? This question must be closed, but it's a good question.

Comment: Name is irrelevant to understanding how it works

Answer (score 2):

This is documented in [their FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) :

> Because HTML has Angular brackets